# Does providing a noisy Vpp for a short period of time affect programming an EPROM?

Tags: programmer, eprom

I have been designing a complex(from my perspective) EPROM Programmer with an ARM-based STM32f103C MCU -actually it's a bluepill board- , I already programmed my EPROM before by hand manually and even had another question here on Electronics stack exchange related to the same EPROM asking about another thing. I don't have any backgrounds in reading datasheets, as I am still in school not yet in college, so I found a statement in the datasheet of my EPROM which I didn't understand and wanted one to help me in it....

My EPROM is a UV "M27C256B-12F1" EPROM, The statement is repeated in Table 7 till Table 10, so I guess it's a very important note.

> VCC must be applied simultaneously with or before VPP and removed simultaneously or after VPP.

This is the [datasheet](https://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/STMicro_M27C256B_EPROM_2384.pdf) the tables starts in **page 5**

From my little understanding, I think that this statement says that VCC should be provided before Vpp and removed after Vpp, but what if the Vpp is provided multiple times while Vcc is still HIGH or on ?

For example:

```
            _______     ______     ____
 VPP:   ___/       \___/      \___/
            ___________________________
 VCC:   ___/
```

The reason why I ask is because the VPP is gonna be provided through a tactile switch which can provide a noisy output like that: (or me accidentally flipping the switch two times(

```
   |--- not stable --||-----stable-------|
    __     ______     ____________________
___/  \___/      \___/
```

And actually when I programmed the EPROM manually I used a switch but only programmed two addresses, now I gonna programmed the full 32-kilo address with a programmer I made and I would like my work and circuit to be clean... and to be sure the EPROM is taking nice wave-forms which won't effect it in the long run.....

In a nutshell, my question is is it bad to provide Vpp multiple times while Vcc is on ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What the datasheet is saying is essentially “don’t have Vpp on unless Vcc is also on”. It is perfectly valid to turn Vpp on and off while Vcc is on. In fact, normal operation would be to have Vcc on continuously while turning on Vpp only when you need to program the device.

You’re fine.